# How can i find the first letter in a line[A to Z] of a file when the line is full of spaces

Tags: bash

I have a file with 5 empty spaces and then a letter, how can i show the position of the first letter in a line?
Something like

```
"    version"
```

And it should return me 5 since it starts on the 5th position

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can do it relatively easily with *parameter expansion* that trims all non-space characters from the right, leaving only the spaces which you store in a variable and then use the *length* parameter expansion to get the count, e.g.

```
$ line="     version"; nspaces="${line%%[![:space:]]*}"; echo "${#nspaces} spaces"
5 spaces
```

**Explanation**

- `nspaces="${line%%[![:space:]]*}"` which uses the parameter expansion form `${parameter%%word}` with the inverted POSIX *character-class* `[:space:]` to trim all non-space characters from the right leaving only leading spaces;
- `echo "${#nspaces} spaces"` simply uses the `${#parameter}` form to obtain the length of spaces in `nspaces`.

Let me know if that is what you were looking for and if you have any questions.